# Sending docker stats over Cloudwatch

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an Ubuntu instance running on EC2 set up with Cloudwatch. I'm successfully sending memory statistics with my setup so I know it's working.

What I want to do now is send stats about the containers running on the Ubuntu docker instance to CloudWatch but I'm not finding any resources on how to define these custom metrics in the config file.

`/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json`

Like sending the `docker ps -a` table or the `docker stats` output to CloudWatch.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you refer to [custom metrics from an EC2 Linux instance to CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-custom-metrics/) document from AWS.

Comment: Ended up using this [tutorial](https://devcloud.co.za/ecs-monitor-container-level-cpu-and-memory-using-docker-stats-and-cloudwatch-metrics/) thanks